# SQL Find names that contain a letter (without using Like)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, substring

I need to write a select statement that returns all last names from a column that contains the letter A. I can't use `LIKE`. I am trying to do so with `SUBSTR`.

Comment: What flavour of sql?

Comment: OK. Sounds great. Tell us when you succeeded. Or did you have any question here?

Comment: Oracle SQL. I'm having trouble formatting the SUBSTR. I have the column, location for the first character to check but I don't know how to put in 'a' as the criteria to return the names. (last_name, 1, ?) Not sure if I set it = to 'a' or include the 'a' in the parenthesis.

Comment: You should probably include all of the above in your question.

Comment: Sound like homework to me.  I think homework questions are OK but most people would look for more effort.

Comment: *Why* can't you use `LIKE`?  Without knowing the background this question will never be helpful to anyone else, and is thus not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `substr` is the way to go. [`instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm), on the other hand, may do the trick:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR(last_name, 'A') > 0
```

EDIT:
As David Bachmann Jeppesen mentioned, Oracle is case sensitive, so if you want to find last names containing any case of "A", you could do something like this:

```
SELECT last_name
FROM   mytable
WHERE  INSTR(UPPER(last_name), 'A') > 0
```

Comment: I appreciate it Mureinik! > 0 returns it only if there is at least 1 name that contains an 'A'?

Comment: Perfect. Just in case - remember that Oracle is case sensitive. :)

Comment: @chaosdecides: It returns all rows in which last_name contains 'A'.

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen good point, thanks. Edited this in to my answer.

Comment: The INSTR function returns the index on which the first occurrence of the char is found and returns 0 if it is not found.